# Using Selenium to get image src inside of a link

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to get some info from this page using Selenium:

[https://www.bandsintown.com/e/1024477910-hot-8-brass-band-at-the-howlin'-wolf?came_from=253&utm_medium=web&utm_source=city_page&utm_campaign=event](https://www.bandsintown.com/e/1024477910-hot-8-brass-band-at-the-howlin%27-wolf?came_from=253&utm_medium=web&utm_source=city_page&utm_campaign=event)

I want to get the `src` of the image on the right side of page.

[image]

Here's the page inspector - the `src` tag I'm trying to get is circled:

[image]

I need to access the `src` without referencing any explicit div names, so what I want to do is find the `href` instance which contains the image, and then search for the image inside of the `a` tag.

Here's my code, which fails to retrieve anything (printing `find_src` prints nothing) :

```
find_src = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a[href^="https://www.bandsintown.com/a/"]//img').get_attribute("src")
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please retry by replacing your css selector expression with this one: "a[href^='https://www.bandsintown.com/a/'] img". So, your rectified code will be:

```
find_src = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[href^='https://www.bandsintown.com/a/'] img").get_attribute("src")
```

If we want to select a descendant element using CSS selectors, space " " is used but in your CSS selector expression, "//" is there. For more information, kindly refer this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

Comment: Thanks Rahul!  Unfortunately it's still not retrieving the src with your updated code... hmm.